# Browser prematurely closes connection

Tags: http, connection

I am working on a legacy system where an intermittent problem keeps happening at what seems to be times where there is a lot of load on the network. I am using IE6 to access a webpage generated by a CGI-script (the actual HTML generation takes quite a bit of time as well), and the problem manifests itself  by cutting the HTTP response short, so all HTML code does not get sent to the browser which renders an incomplete page. I initially thought that this might have something to do with timeouts on the server side, but all the timeouts seem to be quite normal and I cannot see any errors at relevant times in the HTTPERR log.

However, looking at Wireshark logs, it seems like the server sends part of the data, and then client sends a "FIN, ACK" to the server to begin to close the TCP connection some seconds before the server starts to send the rest of the data, which the client then does not want to handle because it thinks that the connection is no longer active.

Does anybody have any tips how I can find out why the IE6 would prematurely cancel a connection?

Comment: Speeding up the ancient web app isn't an option? This is 2013, after all. IE6 is a walking corpse, and that web app is probably close to the same.

Comment: @MichaelHampton +1 for calling IE6 a walking corpse. lol

Answer (score 2):

You could try adjusting the default timeout value of IE.  See this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813827) for more information.